# When are C++ objects destroyed in Objective-C++?

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c++

I am trying to expose a C++ object by creating an Objective-C++ class to wrap it.

Ultimately, in Swift, I'm trying to write this:

```swift
print(JSApplication.eval("'TKTK'")?.toString() ?? "")
print(JSApplication.eval("x = {a: 42}; x")?.toString() ?? "")
print(JSApplication.eval("x")?.get("a")?.toString() ?? "nope");
print(JSApplication.eval("1 + 2")?.toInt32() ?? 0)
```

However, when I try to call `JSApplication.eval("x")?.get("a")?.toString()`, Objective-C calls `dealloc` on my class after `.get("a")` but before `.toString()`.

Normally in `dealloc` I would call `.reset()` on the shared pointer that the class contains. But since the dealloc is firing too early, this would clear out my V8 result before `.toString()` could be called on it.

This raises a general question: How does Swift / Objective-C decide *when* to call dealloc on a temporary object? For something like `foo()?.bar()?.baz()`, where foo and bar return temporary objects, is it correct that both temp objects are receiving a `dealloc` message before `baz` is called? That's what I'm seeing.

If that's the correct behavior, then what's the proper way to extend the lifetime of a temporary object to the scope where the function is being called, like C++? Is that possible?

Here's my Objective-C++ binding. (I notice that no "Destroy 0x..." messages are being printed out at all, so C++ destructors don't seem to be firing. Am I supposed to call those manually?)

```c
// Extracts a C string from a V8 Utf8Value.
const char* ToCString(const v8::String::Utf8Value& value) {
  return *value ? *value : "<string conversion failed>";
}

@interface NJSValue (V8)
- (instancetype)init;
- (instancetype)initWithValue:(Local<Value>)value;
@end

struct NJSRef
{
  std::shared_ptr<Nan::Persistent<Value>> _ref;
  ~NJSRef()
  {
    printf("Destroy 0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)(size_t)_ref.get());
  }
};

@implementation NJSValue (V8)
NJSRef m;

- (instancetype)init
{
  self = [super init];
  return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithValue:(Local<Value>)value
{
  self = [super init];
  Nan::HandleScope scope;
  Nan::EscapableHandleScope escape;
  m._ref.reset(new Nan::Persistent<Value>(escape.Escape(value)));
  printf("Alloc 0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)(size_t)m._ref.get());
  return self;
}
@end

@implementation NJSValue
- (void)dealloc
{
  printf("Dealloc 0x%08x\n", (unsigned int)(size_t)m._ref.get());
  //m_ref.reset();
}

- ( NSString * _Nonnull )toString
{
  if (m._ref != nullptr) {
    Nan::HandleScope scope;
    Local<Value> value(Nan::New(*m._ref));
    v8::String::Utf8Value str(JS_ISOLATE(), value);
    const char* cstr = ToCString(str);
    return NJSStringToNSString(JS_STR(cstr));
  } else {
    return @"undefined";
  }
}
- (NSNumber *)toInt32
{
  if (m._ref != nullptr) {
    Nan::HandleScope scope;
    Local<Value> value(Nan::New(*m._ref));
    if (!value->IsInt32()) return nullptr;
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:TO_INT32(value)];
  } else {
    return nullptr;
  }
}

- (NSNumber *)toNumber
{
  if (m._ref != nullptr) {
    Nan::HandleScope scope;
    Local<Value> value(Nan::New(*m._ref));
    if (!value->IsNumber()) return nullptr;
    return [NSNumber numberWithDouble:TO_DOUBLE(value)];
  } else {
    return nullptr;
  }
}


- (NJSValue * _Nullable __strong)get:(NSString * _Nonnull)key  CF_RETURNS_RETAINED
{
  if (m._ref == nullptr) return nullptr;
  v8::HandleScope scope(JS_ISOLATE());
  v8::EscapableHandleScope handle_scope(JS_ISOLATE());
  Local<Value> value(Nan::New(*m._ref));
  if (!value->IsObject()) return nullptr;
  Local<Object> obj(JS_OBJ(value));
  Local<Value> jsKey(JS_STR([key UTF8String]));
  if (!obj->Has(JS_CONTEXT(), jsKey).FromJust()) return nullptr;
  Local<Value> result(obj->Get(jsKey));
  v8::String::Utf8Value str(JS_ISOLATE(), result);
  const char* cstr = ToCString(str);
  printf("got %s\n", cstr);
  NJSValue* ret = [[NJSValue alloc] initWithValue:handle_scope.Escape(result)];
//  [self associateValue:ret withKey:key];
  return ret;
}
@end

@implementation JSApplication

- (instancetype)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
   }
   return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self) {
     self.frame = frame;
   }
   return self;
}

// Executes a string within the current v8 context.
v8::Local<v8::Value>
ExecuteString(v8::Isolate* isolate, v8::Local<v8::String> source,
                   v8::Local<v8::Value> name, bool print_result,
                   bool report_exceptions) {
  v8::EscapableHandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  v8::TryCatch try_catch(isolate);
  v8::ScriptOrigin origin(name);
  v8::Local<v8::Context> context(isolate->GetCurrentContext());
  v8::Local<v8::Script> script;
  if (!v8::Script::Compile(context, source, &origin).ToLocal(&script)) {
    // Print errors that happened during compilation.
    if (report_exceptions)
      ReportException(isolate, &try_catch);
    return handle_scope.Escape(v8::Undefined(isolate));
  } else {
    v8::Local<v8::Value> result;
    if (!script->Run(context).ToLocal(&result)) {
      assert(try_catch.HasCaught());
      // Print errors that happened during execution.
      if (report_exceptions)
        ReportException(isolate, &try_catch);
      return handle_scope.Escape(v8::Undefined(isolate));
    } else {
      assert(!try_catch.HasCaught());
      if (print_result && !result->IsUndefined()) {
        // If all went well and the result wasn't undefined then print
        // the returned value.
        v8::String::Utf8Value str(isolate, result);
        const char* cstr = ToCString(str);
        printf("eval result: %s\n", cstr);
      }
      return handle_scope.Escape(result);
    }
  }
}


void ReportException(v8::Isolate* isolate, v8::TryCatch* try_catch) {
  v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  v8::String::Utf8Value exception(isolate, try_catch->Exception());
  const char* exception_string = ToCString(exception);
  v8::Local<v8::Message> message = try_catch->Message();
  if (message.IsEmpty()) {
    // V8 didn't provide any extra information about this error; just
    // print the exception.
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", exception_string);
  } else {
    // Print (filename):(line number): (message).
    v8::String::Utf8Value filename(isolate,
                                   message->GetScriptOrigin().ResourceName());
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context(isolate->GetCurrentContext());
    const char* filename_string = ToCString(filename);
    int linenum = message->GetLineNumber(context).FromJust();
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%i: %s\n", filename_string, linenum, exception_string);
    // Print line of source code.
    v8::String::Utf8Value sourceline(
        isolate, message->GetSourceLine(context).ToLocalChecked());
    const char* sourceline_string = ToCString(sourceline);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", sourceline_string);
    // Print wavy underline (GetUnderline is deprecated).
    int start = message->GetStartColumn(context).FromJust();
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
      fprintf(stderr, " ");
    }
    int end = message->GetEndColumn(context).FromJust();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
      fprintf(stderr, "^");
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    v8::Local<v8::Value> stack_trace_string;
    if (try_catch->StackTrace(context).ToLocal(&stack_trace_string) &&
        stack_trace_string->IsString() &&
        v8::Local<v8::String>::Cast(stack_trace_string)->Length() > 0) {
      v8::String::Utf8Value stack_trace(isolate, stack_trace_string);
      const char* stack_trace_string = ToCString(stack_trace);
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", stack_trace_string);
    }
  }
}


+ (NJSValue *)Eval:(NSString *)string  __attribute((ns_returns_retained))
{
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
  v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
  const char* str = [string UTF8String];
  Local<Value> result = ExecuteString(
      context->GetIsolate(),
      v8::String::NewFromUtf8(context->GetIsolate(), str,
                              v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked(),
      JS_STR("JSApplication.Eval"), false, true);

  return [[NJSValue alloc] initWithValue:result];
}

@end
```

Here's the output I get for the Swift code at the top of this question:

```
TKTK
Alloc 0x81d34230
Dealloc 0x81d34230
Alloc 0x81d34270
Dealloc 0x81d34270
TKTK
Alloc 0x81d38230
Dealloc 0x81d38230
[object Object]
Alloc 0x81d38250
got 42
Alloc 0x81d38240
Dealloc 0x81d38240
Dealloc 0x81d38240
42
Alloc 0x81d38250
Dealloc 0x81d38250
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A big part of your problem is that your declaration of `NJSRef m;` is not declaring an instance variable, even though it's inside an `@implementation`. It's just a file-scope global. There's just one, and it's being shared (and clobbered) by all of your instances of `NJSValue`. You would have to enclose it in curly braces `{...}` to make it an instance variable.

That explains why it's never destroyed, at least. Probably a lot of the other symptoms, too, but it's hard to tell given the external types you're using that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: That was exactly the problem! Thanks so much for spotting that. I moved `NJSRef m;` into the initial @interface declaration, in curly braces, and everything works fine now. The downside is that the declaration is in the header, not the source file. I was trying to use categories to keep everything in the source file, but it looks like you can't declare member variables inside categories. Do you know of any alternative?

Comment: Also, do you know where I can find the official specification for Objective-C++? I've been searching, but no results. The clang manual section for Objective-C++ is blank: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#objcxx and apple doesn't seem to have much (or any?) documentation for Objective-C++. Mainly I was hoping to learn from a specification rather than secondhand blog posts / tutorials about Objective-C++.

Comment: You can declare instance variables in the main `@implementation` of the class (not the category that extends the class). I'm not sure why you used a category that just adds the init methods, which are otherwise a pretty central part of a class. So, I recommend that you just incorporate everything that was in the category directly into the class and move the instance variable declaration there, as well.

Comment: I'm not aware of an official specification of Objective-C++. Wikipedia has a [section on it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C++) that seems reasonable. A footnote there directs to a page that's no longer available in Apple's docs, but it's available via the Wayback machine [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100905100849/https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html).

Comment: That's much simpler. I was thinking that since one of the init methods took a C++ type `Local<Value>` that they shouldn't be declared in the @interface, otherwise vanilla Objective-C would get compile errors. But as you say, I can just put it in the @implementation block without declaring it in the @interface at all. Or surround the declaration with `#ifdef __cplusplus` in the @interface. Thanks again, and thanks for the Wayback machine link to Apple's old docs. (I wonder how the clang/gcc authors implemented Objective-C++ without any official docs. The language works wonderfully well.)

Comment: "I wonder how the clang/gcc authors implemented Objective-C++ without any official docs. The language works wonderfully well."
Simple, it was almost certainly implemented by the language's designers at Apple.